# "isGranted" not working in PROD environment

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I build an application with Symfony 2.8.

I created a menu by using **KnpMenuBundle**.

So i'd like to display menu's items when user is not connected and other menu's items when the user is connected of course.

To implement this set ofconditions i used this bunch of instructions below :

```
$security_context = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');

if ($security_context->isGranted(array('ROLE_PSY', 'ROLE_MEMBER'))) { ... }
```

The menu was correctly displayed in "DEV" environnement but unfortunately i encountred this error within the "PROD" env.  :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in C:\xampp_V_5\htdocs\Psych\Psych_web\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:2489 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp_V_5\htdocs\Psych\Psych_web\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1425): appProdUrlMatcher->match('/test') 
#1 C:\xampp_V_5\htdocs\Psych\Psych_web\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1288): Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#2 C:\xampp_V_5\htdocs\Psych\Psych_web\app\cache\prod\classes.php(2484): Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) 
#4 C:\xampp_V_5\htdocs\Psych\Psych_web\app\cache\prod\classes.php(2272): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ in C:\xampp_V_5\htdocs\Psych\Psych_web\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 5233
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache using `rm -rf app/cache/*` command? @HBG404

Comment: yes, I even deleted the cache folder but i have always the same result

Comment: Have you checked `app/console router:debug --env=prod` and `app/console router:debug --env=dev`? Did both contain the route? @HBG404

Comment: I have already used  this two comands to  clean the cache   but  i can't resolve the problem

Comment: ahhh I forgot, i used isGrand when i'd like to display 404 error page, that is to say i put a not found rout

Comment: Using `isGranted` in a custom 404 page [won't work](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5225#issuecomment-7626407)